# Kummer theory if $\ell = p$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, cohomology, galois-theory

**Background.** Let $k$ be a field and let $\ell$ be an integer which is divisible in $k$. Then one has a short exact sequence of abelian étale sheaves
$$ 0 \to \mu_\ell \to \mathbb{G}_m \xrightarrow{(\,\cdot\,)^{\ell}} \mathbb{G}_m \to 0\,\text{,}$$
from which one can deduce interesting applications. It's related to classical Kummer theory, and the connecting map $k^{\times} / \ell \to H^1_{\mathrm{et}}(\operatorname{Spec} k;\mu_\ell)$ gives rise to a map $K_n^{\mathrm{M}}(k)/\ell \to H^n_{\mathrm{et}}(\operatorname{Spec} k ; \mu_{\ell}^{\otimes n})$ (where $K_n^{\mathrm{M}}(\,\cdot\,)$ denotes Milnor K-theory), which appears in the Bloch–Kato conjecture.

**Observation.** If $\ell$ is not divisible in $k$, i.e. $k$ is of characteristic $p$ and $\ell$ is a multiple of $p$, then the above short exact sequence fails to hold the way it's stated, but it *does* hold true if we work with fppf sheaves instead.

**Question.** Are there interesting consequences of the resulting sequence? For instance, is there a version of Kummer theory, and an analogue of the Bloch–Kato conjecture, involving flat cohomology rather than étale cohomology?

Comment: Does the tensor product of $\mu_\ell$ with itself in the fppf world make sense and not degenerate?

Comment: You write that ℓ is divisible in k — do you mean invertible ?

Comment: @MatthieuRomagny I don't remember at all but it sounds reasonable that that was my intention.